# Is make -j distcc possible to scale over 5 times?

Tags: gcc, build, makefile, scalability, distributed

Since distcc cannot keep states and just possible to send jobs and headers and let those servers to use only the data just sent and preprocess and compile, I think the lastest distcc has problem in scalability.
In my local build environment which has appx. 10,000 c/c++ files to build, I could only make 2 times faster than not using distcc (but using make -j) when having 20 build servers.
What do you think is the problem?

If anyone has achieved scalability more than 10 - 20 times using make -j and distcc, please let me know.

The following product claims that it is impossible to scale make -j and distcc faster than 5 times.
http://www.electric-cloud.com/products/electricaccelerator.php

I think this can be improved by:

- Letting the distccd server to maintain sessions
- Tied to those sessions, they will cache their own header directories
- Preprocess will be done demand base from the distccd server
- This will be done through a LD_PRELOADed library libdistcc.so which will replace stat/open syscalls and fetches the header files over network.
  ...

Has anyone done this kind of thing?

---

I think Electric Cloud does similar stuff but I think we have more space to optimize:

1. Servers should share the same source code repository over really fast network filesystem.
2. We should make the build file parsing and include header parsing in parallel.
3. seems to be quite tough without changing the build descriptions drastically.
   Any ideas, prior art, workaround is welcome.

Comment: Have you tried used ccache as well?  The two complement each other very well.

Comment: yes, of course, but I don't have so much interest in ccache improvement because my build system can already avoid rebuilds based on fixdep, basically the same facility with kbuild.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, distcc can scale up well above 5x.

We have to work out what the limiting factor is in your environment.

1. One common problem is that your makefiles won't allow it to actually dispatch more than a couple of files at a time.  You can just have a look at how many compiler processes are running.  If this is the problem you may need to debug your makefiles to allow more parallelism.
2. Perhaps many of the jobs the client is running can't be distributed for some reason.  The distcc client log will tell you if this is the case.
3. Perhaps for some reason the client is overloaded and not able to pass out jobs fast enough; however it's very likely you would get above 2 jobs before hitting this.
4. Perhaps the servers are overloaded and can't accept any more jobs.  But if you have 20 servers they should be able to take at least one each.
5. Perhaps the network is saturated and both the client and server are blocking on it (unlikely on GbE; possible on 100Mb.)

Thinking about hacks to keep sessions open is premature until you know that the limiting factor is starting the sessions.

It's probably #1 or #2.  Post an excerpt from your log.

Comment: Well, basically look for reasons that the dependency chain is overly serialized.  Perhaps it is a recursive make and building only a small number of files per directory at one time.  Perhaps there is a shell `for` loop inside a rule.

Comment: The points 1-4 are all solved in my environment. I'm talking about in ideal case, distcc has problem even when using technique like pump mode: which sends all header files and let distccd to do preprocess as well.

Comment: Logically there must always a rate limiting factor ­— these aren't things you can finally "solve" — you just need to work out what it is.  Are there idle cores on the client or server?  Is the network full?  Are the client processes waiting for disk, waiting for a response from the server, or something else?  What does `distcc-mon` show?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/724314/matt-hargett also suggested, in a rejected edit, that just generally optimizing the source for compile time, by including what you use, will help.  It will help local builds too of course.